# Spring security autoauthentication not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security in my application. When user wants to access /privatePages/* a login screen shows up for authentication. This works fine. I want to have something as a guest access so in my controller I did something like this:

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("SAMPLE", "SAMPLE", getAuthority());
//authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthority() {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new GrantedAuthority() {
        public String getAuthority() {
            return "ROLE_RequiredRole";
        }
    }; 
    grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);
    return grantedAuthorities;
}
```

I can see that authentication is now performed as this expression gives true:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()
```

However I am not able to access `/privatePages/somePage.jsp`. It still redirects me to the login page. Am I missing something ?

**UPDATE**

```
<http pattern="/privatePages/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="myManager" create-session="never">
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/privatePages/login" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/privatePages" access="hasRole('RequiredRole')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/privatePages/" access="hasRole('RequiredRole')"/>
    <form-login
        login-page="/privatePages/login" . . . .
```

Comment: Well, if in your security config you have a permission on `/privatePages/*` like: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/privatePages/*").hasAnyRole("whatever);` then it will enforce the rule on all URLs of the prefix `/privatePages/...`. Instead you should make the `/privatePages/somePage.jsp` to have the `anonymous()` scope, after setting the rule where authentication is required.

Comment: I want it to log in without credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a rule on `/privatePages/**` which means that, the rule will be applied on all URLs with the prefix `localhost:8080/privatePages/...`, and if in that rule you're enforcing some sort of authentication required then it wold ask you regardless of what you do in the Controller because your requests go through the security filter before they reach to that stage.

In your SecurityConfig try doing the following:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/privatePages" access="ROLE_RequredRole" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/privatePages/somePage.jsp" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />  
 </http>
```

Here we are making use of `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` which means that it the role doesn't require any authentication. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html) for more info.

Comment: I did as you told me. It worked without using ROLE_ANONYMOUS. I just had to remove `/privatePages/**`.

Comment: @NoahMartin yeah, so as I was trying to say earlier having `**` in front of a path will enforce all paths after that to also be included into the same rule.